# Use git to create three separate branches and push the branches to three new repos

Tags: git, controls, version, cloning

I'm a relatively new to GIT so I don't want to mess around with it too much incase I accidently delete something. Anyway, at the moment I have a master branch which I have been branching, merging and pushing up to a single repo over the past few months - so far so good. My project has come to a stage now where I need to create three different versions. What I want to do now is create three separate copies of the master branch and have the ability to push them to their own independent Github repo. I know there's a lot already on here about cloning etc but I thought it would best if I asked just to make sure I don't mess anything up. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created the repos on Github, go to your working copy and do

```
git remote add g1 <URL OF REPO1>
git remote add g2 <URL OF REPO2>
git remote add g3 <URL OF REPO3>
```

Now you have three new remotes called `g1`, `g2`, `g3`.

Do an inital fetch of their states:

```
git fetch g1
git fetch g2
git fetch g3
```

And then go ahead and push your current state of `master` there:

```
git push -f g1 master:master
git push -f g2 master:master
git push -f g3 master:master
```

The `-f` flag forces the push, just in case that there are some problems because history doesn't match or whatever. You shouldn't need this in further pushes.

Then, create a local representation of the remote `master` branches:

```
git branch github1-master g1/master
git branch github2-master g2/master
git branch github3-master g3/master
```

Done.

---

Apart of this: before setting up three repos for three versions, check whether these versions couldn't be hosted in one repo with different configurations/build-scripts/whatever. The 3 repo solution has the massive disadvantage that you need to bring most changes that you introduce in `master` into all three version branches (`github1-master`..`github3-master`).

An easier solution would be to have **one** repo that provides **3 different build environments** where you set up your 3 products.

Comment: @Mike: jep. Just execute the commands where your working copy is (i.e. the directory with the `.git` directory below)

Comment: Thanks !! I'll give this a go later. Just a couple of more questions; when you say "go to your working copy" do you mean I should run the "git remote add" command inside my master directory where my .git file resides ?   And secondly, I know you mentioned this in your answer, but if at a later stage I had to merge a change from my master into all three branches how would this be achieved. Thanks again !

Comment: @Mike: best would be to not have three branches. If you insist to, you could either `cherry-pick` or `merge`. It depends on how big the changes are and how big the differences of the `master` branch to the three others is. Once again: if you could solve it through configuration, I'd recommend to use that instead of 3 product branches...

Comment: Sorry about all the questions but how would I solve it using configurations ? Might make it easier for me to merge changes from master to other versions at a later date.